# How to dictionary with python using for loop?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following python script (Some lines not present because not needed):

```
aps = c.get_aps()
ap_names = [{'IP':ap['ip'], 'Name':ap['name'], 'MAC':ap['mac']} for ap in aps]
```

The output is the following:

```
[{'IP': '192.168.30.19', 'Name': 'Antenna #1', 'MAC': '44:d9:e7:be:01:e8'},
{'IP': '192.168.30.24', 'Name': 'Antenna #2, 'MAC': '44:d9:e7:d2:64:1e'}]
```

But when i went to https://jsonlint.com/ to check if the JSON structure is valid before using the data i got the error:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
    [{          'IP': '192.168.30.19
------------^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined
```

I know this is a newbie question and i am sorry. I'm a beginner using this, so please, can someone help me a little bit?

PS: There was another line that was not made by me, which kind of worked but not really for me.

```
ap_names_old = dict([(ap['mac'], ap.get('name')) for ap in aps])
```

This outputs:

```
{'44:d9:e7:be:01:e8': 'Antenna #1', '44:d9:e7:d2:64:1e': 'Antenna #2'}
```

It also returned me a error on JSON Lint and also this doesnt help me at all since i'm trying to build something like this (Which pass OK on JSON Lint check):

```
[{
    "ip": "192.168.1.1",
    "name": "Antenna #1",
    "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx"
}, {
    "ip": "192.168.1.2",
    "name": "Antenna #2",
    "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx"
}]
```

Again - **I am really sorry for this question, i understand this must be a very dumb thing to ask - But i do not know where to go besides StackOverflow, i'm a student/trainnee and do not have a senior to help me where i work at.**

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate any tips, guides, documentations, etc, since i dont mind reading thousands of pages to get this done!

**Edit**

@TimRoberts comment solved this issue.
Final solution was:

```
aps = c.get_aps()
ap_names = json.dumps({'data': [{'{#IP}': ap['ip'], '{#NAME}': ap['name'], '{#MAC}': ap['mac']} for ap in aps]})
print(ap_names)
```

Worked like a charm. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If the first lines you included are all correct, you're missing quotations and using the wrong variable

Comment: Right.  Python prints strings with single quotes, but JSON requires double quotes.  If you want the JSON form of a structure, do `import json` / `out = json.dumps(ap_names)`.

Comment: Typo in your output: `'Antenna #2,` should be `'Antenna #2',`. Not sure how that could happen. Please always copy/paste exactly.

Comment: @jarmod Hi, yeah that typo was not from the output, i typed manually since the output was just a infinite line with other Antennas

Comment: The string represenatation of dictionaries are not oging to give you valid JSON. If you want to create valid JSON, use the `json` module

Comment: @TimRoberts Your solution worked. Thanks, the problem was with the single quotes indeed... Have a nice day!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would use json module and its function json.dumps().

```
import json
a = [dict({'IP': '192.168.30.19', 'Name': 'Antenna #1', 'MAC': '44:d9:e7:be:01:e8'}), dict({'IP': '192.168.30.24', 'Name': 'Antenna #2', 'MAC': '44:d9:e7:d2:64:1e'})]
print(a)  # output in jsonlint gives your error
print(json.dumps(a))  # now correct in jsonlint.
```

Comment: Hi. Yes, i know how to do it normally. I am trying to build this dictionary using a for loop tho... Like, theres more than 30 antennas here, and my for loop is able to print all of them (For ANTENA in ANTENAS - Print name, ip, mac...) - I need to generate a dictionary of the for loop output (So "Antena 1" on first loop, Antena 2 second loop, etc.)

Comment: why do you using `dict()` and passing in a `dict` type to the constructor method?